# Gradient at a point leads to 0/0?

Tags: calculus

A question from a textbook reads:

"A curve has parametric equations $x=t+\sin t$, $y=\cos t$. Find the equation of the tangent to the curve at the point where $t=\pi$."

When working through the problem I reach that $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\sin t}{1+\cos t}$. The book's worked solution then says that when $t=\pi$ that $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$. I am confused, however, as this would lead to assuming that $\frac{0}{0}=0$.

Can someone please explain? Is there a straight forward answer, or are the reasons behind this beyond the scope of the A-Level course?

Comment: Note that: $$\lim_{t \to \pi^-} -\frac{\sin t}{1+\cos t}=-\infty$$ Which would mean an infinite slope, so an equation could only be $x=\pi$. This is not quite rigorous though but it works well enough.

Comment: So you can't just use the parametric derivatives to get the line in terms of a point and a direction vector, because the parametric derivatives are zero, so the direction vector of the line when parametrized by $t$ is just the zero vector. The correct mathematical answer to this is to reparametrize the curve in such a way that the speed isn't zero.

Comment: (Cont.) But a quick-and-dirty calculus answer is to assume that either the slope or the reciprocal slope will be continuous everywhere, so look $\lim_{t \to \pi} \frac{dy}{dx}$ (and if it is infinite then presumably you have a vertical line). This assumption isn't actually mathematically valid, but it will get you through this problem.

Comment: Graphing this shows the slope isn't zero. Are you sure the book didn't say $\frac{dx}{dy}=0?$  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fqt1l8dqpv

Comment: Maybe either a typo or else they are incorrectly describing the tangent at a cusp as being flat when actually it is vertical.

Comment: As you have figured out, the function is not differentiable at that point but the curve has a vertical tangent with equation $x=\pi$.